# How to see the changes after installing bootswatch in JHipster 4

Tags: jhipster, bootswatch

I installed JHipster 4 and followed all the steps given at https://jhipster.github.io/ to install and run the application (Monolithic, no SCSS).

All is working fine and I installed bootswatch (https://jhipster.github.io/modules/marketplace/#/details/generator-jhipster-bootswatch)

But when I restart the app again (running "mvnw" in one console and "yarn start" in the second console), I do not get the footer dropdown list.

Do I have something extra to do?

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing this out. I guess I should go for JHipster 3, as I cannot get the modules to work for JHipster 4 (e.g., Bootstrap Material Design). That's a pity :(

Comment: Yes I do use Angular 4. I will give it a try with Angular 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[generator-jhipster-bootswatch](https://jhipster.github.io/modules/marketplace/#/details/generator-jhipster-bootswatch) does not support Angular 2+, there's an [opened issue](https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-bootswatch/issues/10).

So your alternatives are:

- select Angular 1 as client framework when generating your app
- follow the Bootswatch 4 instructions to manually install it in an Angular 4 JHipster app, it's only CSS if you don't need dynamic theme selection